# Is it possible to embed images in e-mail message in Sharepoint?

Tags: html, sharepoint, email, sharepoint-2007

Currently I'm sending E-Mail messages by SPUtility.SendMail. I'd like to embed images into my message so i can give it a little bit style (div backgrounds, logo images etc.).

Is this possible?

P.S. I can't give direct URL addresses to image SRCs because the resources are located in a site which belongs to a private network which requires authentication for accessing to the files.

### Edit:

I did some research before asking here, ofcourse the first thing i encountered was the System.Net.Mail (do you know that there is a whole web site devoted to it). But the Sharepoint Deployment team in my client's company has some strict rules about custom coding. They have coding guide lines and everything. I'm trying to stick with the SP SDK as hard as i can.

Comment: It certainly *is* possible to embed images in e-mail messages sent via Sharepoint. I have a colleague who sends me a motivational message every day with a huge image. Some of the messages take a minute to load. Why do people do these things??

Comment: My intention is not to abuse people. I'm developing a digest system which sends updates about lists of a SP site. My client wants me to stylize the message so each list summary has its own product logo, color scheme etc.

Maybe i should talk to your colleague then.

Answer (score 4):

The most straighforward way for me has been through using System.Net.Mail, since you can inline your own content.

Here's a sample usage

```
using (MailMessage msg = new MailMessage("fromaddress", "toaddress"))
{
    msg.Subject = "subject";
    msg.Body = "content";
    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp server name");
    smtp.Send(msg);
}
```

Same concept applies to using SPUtility.SendMail (aside from the fact that you'll need a reference to your SPWeb:

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.sendemail.aspx

```
try
{  
    SPWeb thisWeb = SPControl.GetContextWeb(Context);  
    string toField = "someone@microsoft.com";  
    string subject = "Test Message";  
    string body = "Message sent from SharePoint";  
    bool success = SPUtility.SendEmail(thisWeb,true, false, toField, subject, body);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{  
    // handle exception
}
```

The second boolean parameter in SendMail is false to disable HTML encoding, so you can use your <img > and <div > tags in the message body.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I did some research before asking here, ofcourse the first thing i encountered was the System.Net.Mail (do you know that there is a whole web site devoted to it). But the Sharepoint Deployment team in my client's company has some strict rules about custom coding. They have coding guide lines and everything. I'm trying to stick with the SP SDK as hard as i can.